# AWS Transfer Acceleration with pre-signed URLs using JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Simply, is it possible to use transfer acceleration (TA) with pre-signed URLs generated using the AWS-SDK for JavaScript?

Turning on TA for a specific S3 bucket gives a URL with the format: `{bucket}.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`. However, when specifying the parameters for a request, the only valid options seem to be `{Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: 'body', Expires: 60}` and doesn't seem to allow me to say I want to use TA. The resulting URL is in the usual format `{bucket}.s3-{region}.amazonaws.com`, which is wrong for TA.

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) does not seem to offer much information with regards to pre-signed URLs.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, but this is still undocumented and nowhere to be found on their docs or anywhere else (up until now :) ). We got it working by searching in the source code of the SDK. You need to load S3 like this:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({useAccelerateEndpoint: true});
```

Then the SDK will use the accelerated endpoint.

Comment: Ace. That's amazing. Shame it isn't really documented anywhere (yet). Hopefully this will help others interested in taking advantage of this feature, too. Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

As it happens, there is a documented way of enabling S3 transfer acceleration feature on AWS SDK for JavaScript. It can be done by specifying the same property mentioned by @Luc Hendriks but in the AWS.Config class as follow:

```
AWS.config.update({
    useAccelerateEndpoint: true
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Documentation reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html